# Javascript Object from multiple shapes

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am working on a kinda beginners javascript (Canvas) game and I created a mouse shape for the game. I want to get it into a javascript object(Constructor and Prototype) and reduce the amount of code as possible. Could someone help me please. I'm usually pretty good after seeing it once. Thanks in advance. Here is the mouse code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

    <style>
      body {
      margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1200" height="900"></canvas>
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');




 //  ***********************************  Head and Body     **********      
  var bodyX = 0;
  var bodyY = 0;
  var bodyRadius = 25;

  var headX = 22;
  var headY = 0;
  var headRadius = 14;
  // save state
  context.save();

  // translate context
  context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

  // scale context horizontally
  context.scale(2, 1);

  // draw circle which will be stretched into an oval
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(bodyX, bodyY, bodyRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

  // restore to original state
  context.restore();

  // apply styling
  context.fillStyle = '#909090';
  context.fill();
 //***************************************** HEAD  *****************
  context.save();

  // translate context
  context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

  // scale context horizontally
  context.scale(2, 1);

  // draw circle which will be stretched into an oval
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(headX, headY, headRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

  // restore to original state
  context.restore();

  // apply styling
  context.fillStyle = '#707070';
  context.fill();

    //************************************ Right Ear *************
    var rtEarX = 26;
  var rtEarY = 14;
  var rtEarRadius = 8;

    context.save();

  // translate context
  context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

        // draw circle which will be stretched into an oval
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(rtEarX, rtEarY, rtEarRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

  // restore to original state
  context.restore();

  // apply styling
  context.fillStyle = '#707070';
  context.fill();

    //******************************* Left Ear  ***************

  var ltEarX = 26;
  var ltEarY = -14;
  var ltEarRadius = 8;

    context.save();

  // translate context
  context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

        // draw circle which will be stretched into an oval
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(ltEarX, ltEarY, ltEarRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

  // restore to original state
  context.restore();

  // apply styling
  context.fillStyle = '#707070';
  context.fill();

//************************************  Right Eye ********************

    var rtEyeX = 40;
  var rtEyeY = -10;
  var rtEyeRadius = 2;

    context.save();

  // translate context
  context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

        // draw circle which will be stretched into an oval
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(rtEyeX, rtEyeY, rtEyeRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

  // restore to original state
  context.restore();

  // apply styling
  context.fillStyle = '#ff0000';
  context.fill();






    //**********************************  Left Eye ********


  var ltEyeX = 40;
  var ltEyeY = 10;
  var ltEyeRadius = 2;

    context.save();

  // translate context
  context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

        // draw circle which will be stretched into an oval
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(ltEyeX, ltEyeY, ltEyeRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

  // restore to original state
  context.restore();

  // apply styling
  context.fillStyle = '#ff0000';
  context.fill();



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for anyone interested, I spent a lot of hours researching and trial and error and figured it out myself. Here is the code:

// ***********************MOUSE OBJECT *******************

// ************** Properties  ****************************
    function Mousie (){

```
 this.x = 0;
 this.y = 0;
 this.rotation = 0;


}


Mousie.prototype.draw = function (context){



// tail
context.save(); 
context.translate(this.x, this.y);
context.rotate(this.rotation);
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(0,0);
context.lineTo(-100,0);
context.stroke();
context.restore();
// body
context.save();
context.translate(this.x, this.y);
context.rotate(this.rotation);
context.scale(3, 1);
context.beginPath();
context.arc(0, 0, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.fillStyle = '#909090';
context.fill();
context.restore();
// head
context.save();
context.translate(this.x, this.y);
context.rotate(this.rotation);
context.scale(2, 1);
context.beginPath();
context.arc(25, 0, 14, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.fillStyle = '#707070';
context.fill();
context.restore();
// right ear
context.save();
context.translate(this.x, this.y);
context.rotate(this.rotation);
context.beginPath();
context.arc(26, 14, 8, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.fillStyle = '#707070';
context.fill();
context.restore();
// left ear
context.save();
context.translate(this.x, this.y);
context.rotate(this.rotation);
context.beginPath();
context.arc(26, -14, 8, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.fillStyle = '#707070';
context.fill();
context.restore();
// right eye
context.save();
context.translate(this.x, this.y);
context.rotate(this.rotation);
 context.beginPath();
 context.arc(40, 10, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
 context.fillStyle = '#ff0000';
 context.fill();
context.restore();
// left eye
context.save();
context.translate(this.x, this.y);
context.rotate(this.rotation);
 context.beginPath();
 context.arc(40, -10, 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
 context.fillStyle = '#ff0000';
 context.fill();
 context.restore();


};
```